# How to load data from SQL query to model using Dapper?

Tags: dapper

**Model**

```
 Public class EmployeeGroup
    {
    Public int Total {get ;set}
    Public IEnumerable<Employee>{get ;set} 
    }

    Public class Employee
    {
    Public string Name{get ;set}
    Public Location Location {get ;set}
    Public Branch Branch {get ;set}

    }

    Public class Location
    {
    Public string Id {get ;set}
    Public string  Description {get ;set}
    }

    Public class Branch
    {
    Public string Id {get ;set}
    Public string  Description {get ;set}
    }
```

**SQL Query**

```
Select name,l.id,locname,b.id,branchName from
emp e
left join location l on e.locId=l.Id
left join branch b on e.branchId=b.Id
```

Please let me know that how to mapping the property the about query data to model.I have one more query top of the above the query that is providing record count and other paging stuffs so I need to achieve this requirement as per the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dapper doesn't support the kind of projection you're trying to use here - I suggest you create a DTO type that *looks like the data* (i.e. has properties that match the columns), and use `Query<T>` *with that type*, then *separately* expand that to your model.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Marc Gravell....Please provide any sample, if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Marc Gravell...Assume that above model is DTO (i.e., exact DB column) then how we can achieve using Query<T> ?because  `conn.query<EmployerGroup,Employee,Location,Branch,EmployerGroup>`  here my challenge is how to assign IEnumerable items in inside of EmployeeGroup

Comment: @user1611257 that usage is intended to be of the form `conn.Query<Employee,Location,Branch,Employee>(..., (e,l,b) => { e.Location = l; e.Branch = b; return e; });` - but: your columns *don't work for this*. I would just have a DTO **with matching columns**, i.e. `conn.Query<YourDTO>(...).Select(x => new Employee { Foo = x.Foo, Location = new Location { Bar = x.bar } })` etc